# Binding data from db to html

Tags: .net, webforms

I have a small project that sends email to one and in the mail body there is a link that takes to a webform.
The webform goes to sql server data base and by parameters fetches data.
I have a paged data source that gets the dataset and then an accordion that gets the paged data source. i am binding data with Eval most of the time but now there is a requirement for the web form to be more active by javascript.
So the main question is to bind the data to the elements from the server side or to keep it the way it is now. the aspects a speed of the binding data productivity of the web form and good programming form.
Thank for all the answers.

```
<td class="tblHeaderTD">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblArea" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Area")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tblHeaderTD">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblBDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BirthDate","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="tblHeaderTD">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblGender" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Gender")%>'></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you add some code the show both ways?

Comment: <td class="tblHeaderTD">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblBDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("BirthDate","{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")%>'></asp:Label> this is the way i am binding data to elements now.
                                        </td>

Comment: Please add your code in the question